# Failed to resolve entry for package "notistack5". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, es6-modules, commonjs

When running `vite`, I receive the following error:

> 15:52:07 [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve entry for
> package ... The package may have incorrect
> main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve
> entry for package "notistack5". The package may have incorrect
> main/module/exports specified in its package.json.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution, the problem was in the `package.json` file of the `notistack5` module. The `module` file did not exist - ie the correct file name was:

```
"module": "dist/notistack.esm.js"
```

instead of the following (this file didn't exist):

```
"module": "dist/notistack5.esm.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a package with Typescript and I had the same problem and by adding the following codes in `vite.config.ts` my problem was solved

```js
rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
        },
      },
    },
```

My entire `vite.config.ts` code is like this :

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import path from 'path';
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib/index.ts'),
      name: 'notistack5',
      fileName: 'notistack5',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [dts()],
});
```

Answer (score -2):

I addressed this problem by deleting the `node_modules` directory and the `package-lock.json` file, followed by rerunning the `npm install` command.

Answer (score -5):

I had the same problem for me it was to delete de node_module and reinstall all the packages again. It works for me.