# Quasar / Vite Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json

Tags: vite, quasar

I get this error when I try `quasar dev`:

> [ERROR] [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle] Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json: Failed to resolve entry for package "fs". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to resolve entry for package "notistack5". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71363752/failed-to-resolve-entry-for-package-notistack5-the-package-may-have-incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking on the net I found this link with the solution:
[here](https://github.com/nuxt/vite/issues/160#issuecomment-983080874)

The solution for quasar vite is to add this part in quasar.config.js

```
        extendViteConf(viteConf, { isServer, isClient }) {
        // do something with viteConf... change it in-place
        viteConf.resolve = {
          alias: {
            ...viteConf.resolve.alias, // that's important we want to keep the alias set by quasar team
            fs: require.resolve('rollup-plugin-node-builtins'),
            child_process: require.resolve('rollup-plugin-node-builtins'),
          },
        };
      },
```

To save you the trouble to search during hours.